Problemas al intentar realizar una migración, Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''
Estoy realizando un proyecto sencillo en Visual Studio usando Minimal API, cuando intento crear la primera migración me indica el siguiente mensaje de error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MinimalAPIP.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'MinimalAPIP.ApplicationDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

El ApplicationDbContext lo tengo de la siguiente manera:
namespace MinimalAPIP
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Genero> Generos { get; set; }
    }
}

En la clase Program la instrucción del AddDbContext la tengo de la siguiente manera:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));

He visto que en algunos casos este error se suele resolver con un constructor vacío en el ApplicationDbContext, pero no es este caso, porque incluso en el error indica que no puede crear 'DbContext' of type ('')

Intenta con builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
